# How to show that the empty set is in the set of countable union of partition?

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

I am trying to show that the countable union of partitions A form a sigma algebra. I am able to prove every conditions(which is obvious) except that the empty set belongs to A.

I checked the definitions of partition and apparently empty set is not in the set of partitions. And union operation can only make a set bigger which means it is impossible to get empty set.

Is there anything wrong with this problem? Is it that people assume the empty set to be in the partition?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently "countable" means "finite or countably infinite" in that context.

Comment: And? How does it give me the empty set?

Comment: Well, the empty set is finite.

Comment: so the subscript for the union operation here can start from 0? is that something to be assumed when people talk about countability?

Comment: No, I'm talking about an empty union.

Comment: hmm... i am not understanding you then. I only have elements of a partition set and a union operation here to get the empty set. How does empty set being finite or not helps?

Comment: it's not the subscript, it's the superscript, i.e. $\bigcup_{i=1}^0 S_i$

Comment: But I'm not really thinking about indexed union, I like [arbitrary union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Arbitrary_unions) more, i.e. $\bigcup \varnothing$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79480/discussion-between-aha-and-kenny-lau).